# Primary Key on tracking data extracts

Tags: marketing-cloud, data, history-tracking

Is it possible to retrieve a primary key on tracking data extracts (sent, open, click, etc)? I would assume there is a key somewhere on SFDC MC side that identifies a unique record in their tracking database, but I don't see it when I perform a data extract.

This makes it really hard for us to ensure consistent, high quality data so it would be ideal if we could have a PK on each row. Wondering if anyone else has come across this and has a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any Primayr Key in the tracking extract data. You will have to cook up your own key by concatenating field values.  Below is what I used -

SubscriberKey + SendID + EventDate

Comment: That is fine, but often on things other than send (open, click, etc) we get valid, duplicate entries (people clicking the same link multiple times a second). So this method doesn't work for us.